# How do I import non namespaced types into IronPython?

Tags: c#, .net, python, namespaces, ironpython

I have a C# .NET classes that exist outside of a namespace that need to be accessed inside of IronPython. Typically I would do:

```
import SomeNamespace
from SomeNamespace import *
```

However, I do not have a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import your assembly like usual, then just import the class name:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyAssembly") 
import MyGlobalClass
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. I even managed to automate this process using reflection and injecting import execution from .NET